Is it classed as bad practice to use HTTP client inside an SSIS package Task Script C# Over Web Requests
I'm currently working on an SSIS Package update in .Net  Framework 4.7 and i'm creating a new C# script Task.
I am using a legacy script which was originally used, and from the looks of it some time ago.
I wanted to clean up my version of this to follow better practises and be more efficient as I think you should when you go through and clear out the weeds etc, however I am new to SSIS Packages so forgive me.
Basic overview of the script:
Basically this retrieves a large DataSet of string HTTP requests from a DB which are used to make request to an external API and process each record in a loop individually. Add request to a model, then make the request using HttpWebRequest, store the server response for that model write back the response for that record etc.
Issue
The issue is, that this makes use of HttpWebRequest for the HTTP requests, so I have updated mine use HttpClient and Inject it into my helper methods via the Main method then use throughout my scripts lifetime.
As HttpClient only has Async methods i have used them and awaited the response. Im calling the something similar to the below method in a ForEach Loop to make the request for each record in the DataSet.

 public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ReqHelper()
{
 res = await client.GetAsync(url);
}

Because I have awaited the response, but the parent Main method is synchronous and cannot be otherwise (I have read that there is a lot of issues if Async and SSIS packages in general), will I run into issues with the responses going back to different records potentially? I was also worried that it may leave the script task before completing all of the records in the DataSet due to being awaited and move on to the next Task in the Packages control flow without finishing.
I have added this (Which I know is bad practise and shouldn't be used) but I wanted to see if there was another way of ensuring that we didn't move to the next task in the control flow:
MyParentAsyncMethod(InputData).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
My worry was that maybe that's why they were using HttpWebRequest in the first place and I have tried to be clever and make the code better and more up to date.
Forgive me if may if i may be naive in some aspects of this this is my first time working with SSIS packages.
I gladly welcome any advice or assistance from the community on this matter

As HttpClient only has Async methods ... That's not true since .NET 5 HttpClient does have synchronous Send method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.send?view=net-8.0

I should have been clearer. The version we are using  is 4.7 framework on the packages so unfortunatley only asnyc methods are available
